# Sublime Text 3 translate tabs to space feature doesn't work

Tags: tabs, sublimetext3

I've started to learn Haskell today. I've chosen Sublime Text 3 with SublimeHaskell plugin as my IDE. Everything works fine, but when I compile a code the following warning appears:

> Tab character found here. Please use spaces instead.

I've heard that Haskell is white-space sensitive and if tabs really cause some flaws or even bugs why shouldn't I get rid of it?

Unfortunately, when I set `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true` it didn't really help much, the editor doesn't convert any tabs at all. How can I fix that?

My user config:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/SublimeHaskell/Themes/Hasky(Dark).tmTheme",
    "dictionary": "Packages/Dictionaries/Polish.dic",
    "font_size": 8,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "detect_indentation": false,    
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting ST to automatically convert all tabs present in an existing file to spaces?  That setting is just to insert spaces when you press the tab key, it doesn't modify existing tabs.  For that look in the bottom right corner.  There is a bit of text that will say "Tabs: #" or "Spaces: #", click on it and you'll be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. I noticed that when I insert a tab in a new line sublime doesn't convert that, but when I insert inside a line - it does. There must be an additional option perhaps

Comment: @bheklilr thank you, the "convert indentation to spaces" option converts  automatically also any new inserted tab.

Comment: If you want to convert existing tabs to spaces, take a look at the [ReIndent](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ReIndent) package

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I assume it has something to do with the "detect_indentation" setting, since I had to manually replace all tabs for spaces and then close the file and open it again for "translate_tabs_to_spaces" to work. Note that restarting sublime doesn't work, you need to close the specific file(s) that are causing the problem. I assume this is because sublime saves your settings at close.

IMHO this is preferable to having indentation errors because you changed workstations, but it would be nice if sublime would be a bit more verbose about it.